# How Wordpress knows where to find locale files?

Tags: plugins, translation, multi-language

I just used Poedit to translate a plugin with no translations.

I found strings to translate and I generated the .POT file and the .PO and .MO in my language.

I created a folder **languages** in the plugin directory and I put the files in, but it doesn't work.

Do I need to do something to say to my WordPress to look at this folder ? I don't understand what to do.

Comment: The plugin has to use `load_plugin_textdomain` to load the files. Which plugin is concerned ?

Comment: Oh ok, I will take a look and add it myself. The plugin is https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-t-countdown-widget/ (I will fork I think after)

Comment: I look the plugin and it searches the file `wp-content/languages/plugins/jquery-t-countdown-widget-fr_FR.mo` then just put the file in this directory.

Comment: Yes I saw the same, thanks for your help. You can put an answer with the function name, very useful to understand how it works, I will accept.

Comment: I add just a warning about opensource plugins from wordpress.org. If a plugin provide a translation, the file is installed in `languages/plugins` and will erase your custom file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins and themes pull the translation files manually from (mostly) their directory. There are 2 different functions which handle this:

For plugins : [`load_plugin_textdomain()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain)

For themes: [`load_theme_textdomain()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain)

The syntax would be something like this, mostly hooked into `init` or `plugins_loaded` action hook:

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'text-domain', get_template_directory() . '/some-directory' );
```

OR:

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'text-domain', false, basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/some-directory');
```

Look for that in your plugin's php file. After translation, you should paste move the translation file into that directory, and name it as follows, according to [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain):

> The .mo file should be named based on the domain followed by a dash,
>   and then the locale exactly. For example, the locale for German is
>   'de_DE', and the locale for Danish is 'da_DK'. If your plugin's text
>   domain is "my-plugin" the Danish .mo and.po files should be named
>   "my-plugin-da_DK.mo" and "my-plugin-da_DK.po" Call this function in
>   your plugin as early as the init action.

Comment: Perfect explanation.